# Cannot read property 'array' of undefined error occurring in my genymotion while running my react-native project

Tags: react-native

I recently upgraded an old project that was running in react-native 0.49 to 0.55. So after installing and running the project this pops up. I searched the internet and i did not found any solution. Please help.

[image: Screenshot of my emulator]

Comment: Do you get any additional messages in the console when debug is on? If not, one thing I would do is try to take components out from the app, start small, and restore components until you get the error again.

Comment: Thanks @Yossi for your time. I just solved it. I changed the `import PropTypes from 'react'` to `import PropTypes' from 'prop-types` in the **index.js** of a dependency which is being used by **DoctorTiming.js** (shown in the red box).

Answer (score 1):

Solved. For anyone like me facing this issue. Check your red box and you can see the module where the error is targeting. In my case it was **DoctorTiming.js** (Check the image in my question. One error is pointing towards it).

- Go to that module check if it is importing from any dependencies.
- If it does go to node_modules/your_dependency
- Check for **index.js**.
- Inside it change `import PropTypes from 'react'`  to   `import PropTypes from 'prop-types'`.

You are good to go after that.